# Sorting using Mongo template not working in java

Tags: mongodb, mongotemplate

Sorting using MongoTemplate not working in java.

`query.with(new Sort(Sort.Direction.DESC, "numberOfVotes"));

{
            "ideaId": "2",
            "numberOfVotes": "5",
  },
  {
            "ideaId": "3",
            "numberOfVotes": "5",
  },
 {
            "ideaId": "16",
            "numberOfVotes": "17",
  },

ideaId is the primary key.

Comment: Can you please share the sample actual and expected output?

Answer (score 0):

I think the code should be like this:
 `query.with(Sort.by(Direction.DESC, "numberOfVotes"));` this. Can you please try with this?

Comment: When I'm changing direction DESC to ASC, it's giving me the right output.

Comment: that's strange. I tested with my data and it's working as expected.

Comment: numberOfVotes is an integer field. This function is working fine for Date field.

Comment: the data that you have provided indicates that `numberOfVotes` is stored as a string. Could you please check the data type of this field.

Comment: Ya, I changed the data type later to Integer and Double, it was still giving weird results.